# watch is not working inside directive link in angularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Save Button shoud get disable when their is an error message

```
<user-textbox name="txtbox" error-Message="errormsg"></user-textbox>
<button  id="modalSaveButton" type="button" ng-click="save()" data-dismiss="{{ errormsg ? '' : 'modal' }}" value="Save"></button>
```

Directive

```
            link(scope) {   
                        scope.errormsg = false;
                        function disableSave (n, o) {
                          const eleModalSave = 
                                angular.element(document.querySelector('#modalSaveButton'));
                                if(scope.errormsg) {
                                   eleModalSave.attr('disabled',"");
//save button should get disable if errormsg is true
                                } else {
                                   eleModalSave.removeAttr('disabled');
                                }
                        }

                        scope.$watch('errormsg',disableSave, true);
                    }
```

O/P: Save button is not getting disable even if their is an error

Comment: Could you please add your full directive code and controller, thx.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

so in the directive markup you have written:

```
<user-textbox name="txtbox" error-Message="errormsg"></user-textbox>
```

Could you please change attribute name to error-message in the markup. 
So it looks like:

```
<user-textbox name="txtbox" error-message="errormsg"></user-textbox>
```

Angular will translate this on the scope to $scope.errorMessage,
which means your directive declaration should look like:

```
.directive('userTextbox', function(){
  scope : {
     errorMessage :'='
  },
  link : ['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.$watch('errorMessage', function(newVal, oldVal) {

     })]
  }
})
```

Comment: also you shouldn't watch the property errormsg  but rather what you assign it to, that is error-message which in the directive scope becomes errorMessage like I wrote in the answer, hope its understandable

Comment: can you say for sure $scope.errorMessage is on your scope?

Comment: I've created a jsbin where the watch expression is being triggered, https://jsbin.com/qigene/edit?html,js,console,output